# SSH hangs at 'debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent'

Tags: linux, ssh, centos

I am encountering this strange problem where, in host A, SSH stops at 'debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent' and just hangs there indefinitely.

However, there is another host B which is the next IP address to A where SSH is working fine to the same device. I am able to SSH to a few other devices from host A without issues.

Here are some points:

1. Host A and B are in the same subnet ( adjacent IP addresses )
2. Hosts A and B are actually VMs in the same ESXi server ( should be configured similarly )
3. A and B both are CentOS VMs, with similar kernel and sshd version/config
4. One time when this issue happened before, a reboot fixed it, but unsure as to why that was.

   5. Tried to restart sshd and also network service but no use.
   6. They have same MTU - 1500

I also tried to use local port forwarding like A->B->device and it worked this time but B->A->device did not. ( host A is the one unable to SSH directly )

I can't seem to paste the verbose log due to restrictions, but these are the few last lines:

debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug2: Wrote 960 bytes for a total of 981

Also, from Wireshark,  I see that the client initiates Key exchange but the server never responds. The end device( Cisco router ) logs "%SSH-4-SSH2_UNEXPECTED_MSG: Unexpected message type has arrived. Terminating the connection"

Any suggestion on what is happening here?

Answer (score 3):

I hit the same issue, and it seems like an MTU issue. Try this on your trouble machine:

```
echo "1454" > /sys/class/net/eth0/mtu
```